# How do I prevent action bar in an activity from moving up and disappearing?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity with several entry fields. I has an action bar. When I move down, at a certain point, the action bar starts to move up, and if I enter some entry fields further down, the action bar disappears totally.

How do I ensure that the action bar is fixed at the top and does not disappear, even if there are many fields down the window?
...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    ... other horizontal LinearLayout follow...
```

...
One solution is to use ScrollView as "root" layout, then only one direct dependent Layout (such as a LinearLayout) that will serve as container for all other necessary layouts and components needed to your activity.
...
Such as:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
    ... all other necessary layouts here...



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "Googled" the problem and could not find the same type of problem described, and no solution.

It is when I was viewing Udacity NanoDegree Lesson on Developing Android Apps that I saw the use of ScrollView. So the solution is to use a ScrollView as the root layout, then a single LinearLayout that will be the container of all other necessary layouts and views needed for your activity. ScrollView can only one dependent. [See YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XddHn8Iza7w)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Toolbar and place it into the linear layout as a sibling along with your scroll view. It will look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activityTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>
        ... all other necessary layouts here...



</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure that `android:orientation` is set to "vertical"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

do you mean your action bar is like this and you want to make it stable like the fourth picture?

you need to chandge the theme and make windowActionBarOverlay set to false

from

```
 <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

to
   false